# Turning node.js projects into snap packages

Tags: packaging, snap, nodejs, mongodb

How can I convert node.js applications into Ubuntu snaps?

I found [this page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/blog/2015/06/02/turning-nodejs-projects-snap-packages/) on the Ubuntu developer website but the tutorial has been moved or removed.

My nodejs application is built on MEAN stack.

Comment: You can find the missing guide [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160427045733/https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/snapcraft-advanced-features/).

Comment: Here is a newer nodejs tutorial: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/build-a-nodejs-service#0

Comment: Please, if popey's answer works for you consider setting it as the accepted one. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial referenced is very outdated and likely won't work anymore. Instead, use the node plugin when packaging a nodejs. For example you might use a part like this which also specifies the node version and build dependencies required:-

```
parts:
  slap:
    plugin: nodejs
    source: https://github.com/slap-editor/slap.git
    node-engine: 6.9.5
    build-packages:
      - python
      - make
      - build-essential
```